# Difference in behavior between basic type (int) and complex type (np.ndarray)

Tags: python, numpy

Why are the following objects behaving differently with regard to the `[x] * n` operation?
I.e. why does the first operation (`in[94]`) modify a single entry of the list, whereas the second operation (`in[99]`) modify *all* the entries?

```
In [91]: x = 8

In [92]: y = [x] * 10

In [93]: y
Out[93]: [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]

In [94]: y[1] = 4

In [95]: y
Out[95]: [8, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]

In [96]: x = np.zeros(shape=(3,3))

In [97]: y = [x] * 10

In [98]: y
Out[98]: 
[array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])]

In [99]: y[1][1,2] = 5

In [100]: y
Out[100]: 
[array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  5.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  5.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  5.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  5.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  5.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  5.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  5.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  5.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  5.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  5.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])]
```

Comment: You would get the same behavior if you replicated a list, e.g. `x=[0,0,0];y=[x]*4;y[1][1]=2`.

Comment: So it's about compound types in general rather than about `np.ndarray`  specifically then.

Comment: Right, any mutable object.  As long as you are just copying pointers, modifying one modifies them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr : You implicitly made a [shallow copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Shallow_copy) of the matrix when you were expecting a deep copy.** [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)

Consider the following bit of code:

```
In [38]: import numpy

In [39]: a = numpy.eye(2)

In [40]: a
Out[40]:
array([[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])

In [41]: b = a

In [42]: b
Out[42]:
array([[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])

In [43]: a[0,0] = 2

In [44]: a
Out[44]:
array([[ 2.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])

In [45]: b
Out[45]:
array([[ 2.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])
```

Also:

```
In [46]: id(a)
Out[46]: 140529107552512

In [47]: id(b)
Out[47]: 140529107552512
```

I defined `a`. Set `b=a` and then changed `a` to find the same change in `b` even though I didn't touch `b`.

By your line `[x] * 10`, it made 10 shallow copies of `x`. So, change in any one reflects on all others.

```
In [90]: x = np.zeros(shape=(3,3))
In [95]: y = [x] * 10

In [96]: id(y[0])
Out[96]: 140529110575952

In [97]: id(y[1])
Out[97]: 140529110575952

In [98]: y[1][1,2] = 5

In [99]: id(y[0])
Out[99]: 140529110575952

In [100]: id(y[1])
Out[100]: 140529110575952
```

This is not a problem for `int` or [any other non-compound type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html).

```
In [105]: x = 0

In [106]: y = [x] * 10

In [107]: y
Out[107]: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

In [108]: y[1] = 2

In [109]: y
Out[109]: [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

In [110]: id(y[0])
Out[110]: 140529069263200

In [111]: id(y[1])
Out[111]: 140529069263152
```

Comment: Right. So that would mean that `[x] * n` calls the shallow copy "constructor" n times? But since `int` only defines deep copy,  there is no reference between objects.

Comment: @JGab AFAIK, that is exactly what happens.